# Use variables when looping. (ex: first loop Variable1=value1 and in second loop variable1=value2)

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a small programme which I want to loop through several worksheets. But the problem is in the code I have, there are variables that needs to be changed from worksheet to worksheet. Therefore I can't use the loop command.

In my code (please see below) I have set them as VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2 etc. The values of these should be changed when it run first time, second time and so on.

Example:

In the First Loop `VARIABLE1` should be equal to `"CMGLT"` and in the
Second Loop `VARIABLE1` should be equal to `"CMCLT"`.

```
Function WorksheetExists(WSName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = Worksheets(WSName).Name = WSName
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Sub BOI()
    If Not WorksheetExists("VARIABLE1") Then '---------------VARIABLE1
        Sheets.Add.Name = "VARIABLE1" '---------------VARIABLE1
    Else
        'START GEN CODE
        'Set CMGLT as activesheet!!!!
        Worksheets("VARIABLE1").Activate '---------------VARIABLE1
        'Checking company code
        Dim celltxt As String
        celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("G8").Text

        If InStr(1, celltxt, "VARIABLE2") Then '---------------VARIABLE2
            'unmerge entire sheet
            ActiveSheet.Cells.UnMerge
            'unwrap entire sheet
            ActiveSheet.Cells.WrapText = False
            'set short date format for up to 3000 rows
            ActiveSheet.Range("A2", "A3000").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            'delete blank rows in column A
            Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
            'delete rows from 1 to 6
            Rows("1:6").EntireRow.Delete
            'deleting all rows below "total"
            Dim LR As Long, Found As Range
            LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set Found = Columns("A").Find(What:="Total", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not Found Is Nothing Then Rows(Found.Row & ":" & LR).Delete
            'changing column width of B column
            Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 12
            'changing column width of A column
            Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 12
            'changing formating of B column to General
            Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "General"
            'CHANGE THIS AS APPROPRIATELY!!!!
            Range("B1").Value = "VARIABLE3" '------------------------------------'VARIABLE3

            'getting date as value
            Range("C1").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-2],""DD.MM.YYYY"")"

            'copying company code and date until last row of data
            Dim LRow As Long
            LRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & LRow)
            Range("C1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C" & LRow)

            'pasting date as value
            Columns("C:C").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            'deleting blank rows in amount column
            On Error Resume Next
            Range("W:W").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

            'coping data to "UP" sheet
            Dim Lastrow As Integer
            Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Range("C1:C" & Lastrow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Up").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Range("B1:B" & Lastrow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Up").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Range("C1:C" & Lastrow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Up").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Range("Q1:Q" & Lastrow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Up").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Range("Q1:Q" & Lastrow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Up").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Range("W1:W" & Lastrow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Up").Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

            'END GEN CODE
        Else
            MsgBox ("VARIABLE1 Validation Mismatch. Exiting...") '---------------VARIABLE1
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: did you try a for each loop for each sheet in workbook?

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: sure.  it just seems to me if you want to run the same code through all the worksheets in your workbook you would use something like this where you declare a variable as a worksheet like "dim sht as worksheets" then the loop would start out "for each sht in worksheets" enter code in the body then end with "next sht".

Comment: I understand your concept but i'm new to coding so i have little idea how to execute that. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** for some code speed improvements after OP's sharing an example file

you can have your `BOI` sub accept varying strings as parameters and be called by a main sub looping through all of them

like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub main() '<~~ main sub calling BOI inside a loop
    Dim VARIABLE1 As Variant, VARIABLE2 As Variant, VARIABLE3 As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    VARIABLE1 = Array("CMGLT", "CMCLT", "VARIABLE3", "VARIABLE4") '<~~ "main" array containing all VARIABLE1 needed values
    VARIABLE2 = Array("114486744", "104074162", "VARIABLE2-3", "VARIABLE2-4") ' <~~ VARIABLE2 array, with elements corresponding by position to VARIABLE1 ones -> total elements number must match VARIABLE1 one
    VARIABLE3 = Array("VARIABLE3-1", "VARIABLE3-2", "VARIABLE3-3", "VARIABLE3-4") ' <~~ VARIABLE3 array, with elements corresponding by position to VARIABLE1 ones -> total elements number must match VARIABLE1 one

    For i = 0 To UBound(VARIABLE1) ' <~~ loop over your VARIABLE1 array
        Call BOI(VARIABLE1(i), VARIABLE2(i), VARIABLE3(i)) ' <~~ and pass VARIABLE2 and VARIABLE3 corresponding elements, too
    Next i
End Sub

Sub BOI(VARIABLE1 As Variant, VARIABLE2 As Variant, VARIABLE3 As Variant)
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim found As Range

    If Not WorksheetExists(CStr(VARIABLE1)) Then '---------------VARIABLE1
        Sheets.Add.Name = CStr(VARIABLE1)
    Else

        'START GEN CODE
        With Worksheets(CStr(VARIABLE1)) '---------------VARIABLE1 '<~~ instead of selecting/activating wanted sheet, tell VBA to consider it as implicit object for any subsequent methods or properties calls

            'Checking company code
            If InStr(1, .Range("G8"), CStr(VARIABLE2)) Then '---------------VARIABLE2

                'unmerge entire sheet
                .UsedRange.UnMerge '<~~ VBA reads this statement as "Worksheets(CStr(VARIABLE1)).UsedRange.Unmerge"
                'unwrap entire sheet
                .UsedRange.WrapText = False '<~~ act on usedrange only, to be faster

                LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<~~ store last non empty row index

                'clearing all rows below "Total"
                Set found = .Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Find(what:="Total", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<~~ search into relevant cells only
                If Not found Is Nothing Then .Rows(found.Row & ":" & LR).Clear '<~~ Clear() is faster then Delete()

                'set short date format for up to 3000 rows
                LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<~~ update last non empty row index (you possibly deleted some rows before)
'                .Range("A2", "A3000").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
                .Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" '<~~ act on relevant cells only
                'delete blank rows in column A
                .Range("A1:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete '<~~ avoid deleting blank rows after the last non empty one
                'delete rows from 1 to 6
                .Rows("1:6").EntireRow.Delete

                LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<~~ update last non empty row index (you possibly deleted some rows before)
                'changing column width of B column
                .Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 12
                'changing column width of A column
                .Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 12
                'changing formating of B column to General
                .Range("B1:B" & LR).NumberFormat = "General" '<~~ act on relevant cells only
                'CHANGE THIS AS APPROPRIATELY!!!!
                .Range("B1").Value = VARIABLE3 '------------------------------------'VARIABLE3

                'getting date as value
                .Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-2],""DD.MM.YYYY"")" '<~~ instead of selecting and then acting on selection, just act directly on the range object

                'copying company code and date until last row of data
                .Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & LR)
                .Range("C1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C" & LR)

                'pasting date as value
    '            .Columns("C:C").Select
    '            Selection.Copy
    '            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    '                    :=False, Transpose:=False
    '            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                With .Columns("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) '<~~ this is equivalent to what above, but much faster
                    .Value = .Value
                End With

                'deleting blank rows in amount column
                On Error Resume Next
                .Range("W1:W" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete '<~~ act on relevant cells only
                On Error GoTo 0 '<~~ always remember to set standard error trapping right after you don't need skipping errors anymore

                'coping data to "UP" sheet
                LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '<~~ update last non empty row index (you possibly deleted some rows before)
                CopyValues .Range("C1:C" & LR), Worksheets("Up"), "A" '<~~ take advantage of a sub to avoid repeating same code
                CopyValues .Range("B1:B" & LR), Worksheets("Up"), "C" '<~~ take advantage of a sub to avoid repeating same code
                CopyValues .Range("C1:C" & LR), Worksheets("Up"), "D" '<~~ take advantage of a sub to avoid repeating same code
                CopyValues .Range("Q1:Q" & LR), Worksheets("Up"), "F" '<~~ take advantage of a sub to avoid repeating same code
                CopyValues .Range("Q1:Q" & LR), Worksheets("Up"), "I" '<~~ take advantage of a sub to avoid repeating same code
                CopyValues .Range("W1:W" & LR), Worksheets("Up"), "O" '<~~ take advantage of a sub to avoid repeating same code

                'END GEN CODE

            Else
                MsgBox (VARIABLE1 & " Validation Mismatch. Exiting...") '---------------VARIABLE1
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
    End If

End Sub


Sub CopyValues(sourceRng As Range, targetSht As Worksheet, targetCol As String)
    With targetSht
        .Range(targetCol & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(sourceRng.Rows.Count).Value = sourceRng.Value
    End With
End Sub


Function WorksheetExists(WSName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = Worksheets(WSName).Name = WSName
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

where I also made some more (of all possible) little code optimizations too

Comment: I really appreciate the comprehensive answer since i'm not much of a coder. but when i run the code it gives this error, `Run time error 1004- Auto fill method of range class failed` at this line (when i press debug) `.Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & LR)`

Comment: i can share the spreadsheet i'm currently working on here https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmgs79zmwku6wf9/Up.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: to dig into that error is relevant the value of `VARIABLE3` that was put into `B1` cell before. but this is a new issue for which you must start a new question.  whereas if I fulfilled your _**original**_ question please mark my answer as accepted. thank you.  BTW from the file you shared I edited my answer to add some more code speed optimizations (see comments).

Comment: Thanks for the additional improvements too. I have accepted the answer.